# head->next is not null

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I can't figure out why my one item list "_head->next" is not being set to null (nullptr). Could I be confusing my tail and head pointers? This is for a doubly linked list. Most other pointers work, but this error/bug throws a seg fault when walking through the list.

```
#pragma once
class dlist {
  public:
    dlist() { }

  struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
  };


  node* head() const { return _head; }
  node* tail() const { return _tail; }


void insert(node* prev, int value){
     //if empty
     if(prev == nullptr)
       {
       //create node/prepare to insert into head ptr
        _head = new node{value, _head, nullptr};

        if(_tail == nullptr)
        {
         _tail = _head;
         _tail->next = nullptr;
        }
        //set head
        if(_head->next != nullptr)
          {
           _head->prev = _head;

           _head->next = nullptr;
           //_head->next->next = nullptr;
           //above doesn't work  
          }
       }
 //if not empty
     else
       {
       //create and set new node
        node* node1 = new node{value, prev->next, nullptr};
        prev->next = node1;

        //check if null, to make sure inserting after a filled "space"
         if(node1->next != nullptr)
           {
            node1->next->prev = node1;

            //set to end or tail
            if(prev == _tail)
              {
               _tail = node1;
               _tail->next = nullptr;
              }
           }
       }
  }


 private:
   node* _head = nullptr;
   node* _tail = nullptr;

};
```

Comment: This will definitely take a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How are `_head` and `_tail` even visible inside `insert`? Is `insert` a class member function and you are just not showing the rest of the class?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is inside a class. Do you suggest I post the entire class, all functions or only insert? I was told to not post novels.

Comment: The class with the `insert` in a short program that reproduces your problem and that can be compiled and verified by those who help you here. You should not expect that people will write there own class and test code to test your function. By provided a MCVE, you help us help you.

Comment: If you want to be a programmer, learn to use a debugger. Asking someone to solve this for you is not going to help you learn anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stronlgy recommend not using *C-style pointers* in *C++* anymore. *C++* has *smart pointers* that do all the memory management for you.

Change your node to this:

```
class node {
    node(int value) : value{value} {}
    int value;
    std::shared_ptr<node> next;
    std::weak_ptr<node> prev;
};
```

The `shared_ptr` will delete the object it holds as soon as no copy/instance of itself exist anymore (it uses a simple counter). The `weak_ptr` makes sure that you don't have circular references, which would mean your nodes never get deleted.

Also in your *dlist* class change the members accordingly:

```
std::shared_ptr<node> _head;
std::weak_ptr<node> _tail;
```

Then change your getters to this:

```
std::shared_ptr<node> head() const { return _head; }
std::shared_ptr<node> tail() const { return _tail.lock(); }
```

`weak_ptr::lock()` will increase the `shared_ptr` counter it belongs to and return a new `shared_ptr`, that then can be accessed without risk of losing the object. If the object was deleted already, it will return en *empty* `shared_ptr`.

Then change your insert method like this:

```
void insert (int value)
{
    std::shared_ptr<node> newnode = std::make_shared<node>(value);

    if (_tail) {
        newnode->prev = _tail;
        _tail->next = newnode;
        _tail = newnode;
    }
    else {
        _head = newnode;
        _tail = newnode;
    }
}
```

This will set *_head* and *_tail* to the *newnode* if the list is empty, or add it to the end of your list otherwise.

Read more about [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) here.

//Edit: If you ever want to clear your list, you can simply do `_head = nullptr;`. This will cause the `shared_ptr` to decrease it's reference counter and delete the `node` it is holding (if the counter goes to 0), thus deleting the `shared_ptr<node> next;` in that node and so on. `_tail` will automatically be *empty* as soon as the `shared_ptr` it belongs to is deconstructed. To be absolutely sure that your dlist class is in a clean empty state, you should still call `_tail = nullptr;`, because some other part of your code can hold a `shared_ptr` to any of the nodes, thus keeping `_tail` alive in your list class unless you explicitly clear it.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hard one to get your head around given the initial code you posted and the ambiguity in your use of `prev` as a parameter to `insert`.

To begin, `insert` is a member function of `dlist` and has direct access to both `_head` and `_tail`. You do not need a `node*` parameter for `insert` because your only concern with the linked list will be checking whether `_head` is `nullptr` and allocating/assigning `value` for `_head`, or you will iterate until your `iter->next` is `nullptr` and add the allocated node as `iter->next` setting `_tail` to the newly allocated node.

Most of your existing code, frankly, just left me scratching my head. Also, the default for `class` is `private`, so generally you only need to designate `public` members.

Putting the logic together, you could do something like the following:

```
class dlist {

    struct node {
        int value;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    };

    node* _head = nullptr;
    node* _tail = nullptr;

  public:
    dlist() { }

    node* head() const { return _head; }
    node* tail() const { return _tail; }

    void insert (int value)
    {
        node *newnode = new node {value, nullptr, nullptr};

        if (_head == nullptr)
            _head = newnode;
        else {
            node* iter = _head;
            for (; iter->next; iter = iter->next) {}
            newnode->prev = iter;
            _tail = iter->next = newnode;
        }
    }
};
```

When you allocate memory in a class, in order to prevent leaking memory like a sieve, you need to also declare a destructor that will free the memory you have allocated when an instance of the class goes out of scope. Nothing fancy is needed, just iterate from `_head` to the end of the list and `delete` nodes as you go.

(**note:** you must not `delete` your reference to the current node until you have saved a reference to the next node, so use a separate, aptly named `victim` node to perform the `delete`)

You could do something like:

```
    ~dlist() {
        node* iter = _head;
        while (iter) {
            node* victim = iter;
            iter = iter->next;
            delete victim;
        }
    }
```

Putting it altogether and adding a couple of functions to `print` and reverse or `rprint` the list, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dlist {

    struct node {
        int value;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    };

    node* _head = nullptr;
    node* _tail = nullptr;

  public:
    dlist() { }
    ~dlist() {
        node* iter = _head;
        while (iter) {
            node* victim = iter;
            iter = iter->next;
            delete victim;
        }
    }

    node* head() const { return _head; }
    node* tail() const { return _tail; }

    void insert (int value)
    {
        node *newnode = new node {value, nullptr, nullptr};

        if (_head == nullptr)
            _head = newnode;
        else {
            node* iter = _head;
            for (; iter->next; iter = iter->next) {}
            newnode->prev = iter;
            _tail = iter->next = newnode;
        }
    }

    void print () {
        for (node* iter = _head; iter; iter = iter->next)
            cout << " " << iter->value;
        cout << "\n";
    }

    void rprint() {
        for (node* iter = _tail; iter; iter = iter->prev)
        cout << " " << iter->value;
        cout << "\n";
    }
};

int main (void) {

    dlist list;
    int tmp;

    while (cin >> tmp)
        list.insert(tmp);

    list.print();
    list.rprint();
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "2 3 4 6 8 10" | ./bin/dlist
 2 3 4 6 8 10
 10 8 6 4 3 2
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer or reference to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you properly use the memory you allocate, and to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ echo "2 3 4 6 8 10" | valgrind ./bin/dlist
==18878== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18878== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18878== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18878== Command: ./bin/dlist
==18878==
 2 3 4 6 8 10
 10 8 6 4 3 2
==18878==
==18878== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18878==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18878==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 77,968 bytes allocated
==18878==
==18878== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18878==
==18878== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18878== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Comment: Totally torn between upvoting for a detailed and thorough answer, and downvoting because you're not telling OP about smart pointers. I figured I don't vote at all and just leave this comment as a statement.

Comment: Granted yes, `std::unique_pointer` would have handled deletion, but you really should know how to write a destructor in order to appreciate what the smart pointers do. Good point made.

Comment: I wouldn't use `std::unique_pointer` as this is a doubly linked list, so you need at least two pointers per item. Also you have public getters and setters for the nodes, and you can't return a `std::unique_pointer` without losing ownership.

Comment: Now, you start to see why explaining the linked list logic issues was made a whole lot cleaner without losing the OP in getters, setters, deleters and templates. Here the simplicity of a 5-line destructor doesn't mask the complexity of the list logic as a full smart pointer implementation risks doing. KISS for learning, elegance for implementation.

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning. smart pointers are super easy and clean, and people new to C++ shouldn't learn how to implement old C-style pointers in their code, they should learn how to write clean modern C++. (Not saying that it doesn't make sense to understand pointers and how to handle them, but this is about writing new code, not using legacy code.)